# JAX-RS to RAML example not working

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

Here is the scenario. I am new to `RAML`. We've REST services already written with `jax-rs`. Now we want to integrate `RAML` to generate documentation of these API.

I've already installed RAML JAX-RS plugin into eclipse with help from [RAML for JAX-RS](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs)

And also downloaded the repository from [RAML fo JAX-RS on GITHUB](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs)

Examples are given for `jax-rs` to `RAML` [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/tree/master/jaxrs-to-raml/examples)

I've gone through documentation but still struggling to start with actual implementation.

I want to know **how do I run these examples from eclipse and how to generate `RAML` from already written REST API with `jax-rs` ?**

Update:

I've imported examples as existing `maven` project. And tried to generate `RAML` from `HelloWorldRest.java` in examples folder. And getting below error. Please find attache screenshot as well.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [RAML_POC does not exist]
```

[image]

**More update**

**I performed below steps to import:**
Import in Package Explorer -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> Selected root directory of repository -> Seleted availabe 3 projects: com.mulesoft.jaxrs.raml.generator, com.mulesoft.jaxrs.raml.generator.annotations and jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin.

Then open `HelloWorldRest.java`, right-click and select `Generate RAML from classes`. And get the error mentioned.

The git repository struncture is also available in attached screenshot.

Comment: I tried in my local and this doesn't happen. Can you explain how did you run the project?

Comment: @kucing_terbang - added more description. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the error is caused by the fact that you actually haven't set the project as a `"Java Project"`. Thus, the source code you selected (in this case `HelloWorldRest.java`) has not been parsed as a `"Source Code"`.

You could try :

- Import the example project (the `helloworld` project) directly as a maven project rather than `jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin` project. or,
- Set the folder `src/main/java/helloworld/` as a source folder. This can be done by :

  1. First convert the project into faceted form.
  2. Make sure that the `examples/helloworld/src/main/java` is set as a source folder

After you try either one of these steps. Try to generate the RAML again from the class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to run examples now. Could you please  [look into this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251266/illegalstateexception-while-generating-raml) ? Now I am trying to generate RAML from existing JAX-RS REST services.

Comment: could you please look (into this)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272147/not-able-to-generate-raml-from-jax-rs-rest-api]