# Not able to generate RAML from JAX-RS REST API

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I am trying to generate `RAML` from existing `jax-rs` REST API. I've already installed `jax-rs` to `RAML` plugin in eclipse. And it is installed properly as I can run examples properly from eclipse and able to generate `RAML`.

When I tried to generate `RAML` from existing `jax-rs` REST API, I am getting below error.

[image: raml error]

**What could be the reason and solution for this ?**

Comment: is there a compilation error in your workspace?

Comment: @kucing_terbang- I've resolved all comiplation errors. But still I am getting the same "Generate RAML Error".

Comment: Then, you might need to check the "error log view" to see what the error message is; as the error itself is thrown when the plugin trying to resolve some `type/class` but it failed.